# Serial communication - I'm having trouble turning an incoming char array into an int

Tags: c++, arrays, serialization, int, type-conversion

I'm trying to receive a number from an Arduino as an integer in C++.  The full code is below:

```
#define STRICT
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Serial.h"
#include <boost\lexical_cast.hpp>
enum { EOF_Char = 27 };

int __cdecl _tmain(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    CSerial serial;
    LONG    lLastError = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    // Attempt to open the serial port (COM4)
    lLastError = serial.Open(_T("COM4"), 0, 0, false);

    // Setup the serial port (9600,8N1, which is the default setting)
    lLastError = serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud9600, CSerial::EData8, CSerial::EParNone, CSerial::EStop1);

    // Register only for the receive event
    lLastError = serial.SetMask(CSerial::EEventBreak |
        CSerial::EEventCTS |
        CSerial::EEventDSR |
        CSerial::EEventError |
        CSerial::EEventRing |
        CSerial::EEventRLSD |
        CSerial::EEventRecv);

    // Use 'non-blocking' reads, because we don't know how many bytes
    // will be received. This is normally the most convenient mode
    // (and also the default mode for reading data).
    lLastError = serial.SetupReadTimeouts(CSerial::EReadTimeoutNonblocking);

    // Keep reading data, until an EOF (CTRL-Z) has been received
    bool fContinue = true;
    do
    {
        // Wait for an event
        lLastError = serial.WaitEvent();

        // Save event
        const CSerial::EEvent eEvent = serial.GetEventType();


        // Handle data receive event
        if (eEvent & CSerial::EEventRecv)
        {
            // Read data, until there is nothing left
            DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
            char szBuffer[101];
            do
            {
                // Read data from the COM-port
                lLastError = serial.Read(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer) - 1, &dwBytesRead);

                if (dwBytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // Finalize the data, so it is a valid string
                    szBuffer[dwBytesRead] = '\0';

                    // Display the data
                    printf("%s", szBuffer);


                    // Check if EOF (CTRL+'[') has been specified
                    if (strchr(szBuffer, EOF_Char))
                        fContinue = false;
                }
            } while (dwBytesRead == sizeof(szBuffer) - 1);
        }
    } while (fContinue);

    // Close the port again
    serial.Close();
    return 0;
}
```

I have my Arduino constantly sending out the number 51.  This code works fine and consistently displays "51".  However, I want an int to manipulate in C++.

First I added

```
std::stringstream str(szBuffer);
int tester;
str >> tester;
printf("My number is: %d\n", tester+1);
```

right after

```
printf("%s", szBuffer);
```

A typical result looks like:

```
51My number is: 52
51My number is: 52
51My number is: 52
51My number is: 52
51My number is: 52
5My number is: 6
1My number is: 2
```

After doing it perfectly 5 or 6 times, the output always separates the incoming digits once or twice in a row (I haven't been able to find a specific pattern yet, but it's always 5-6 and 1-2).

My other attempt was to use the boost library:

```
int tester = boost::lexical_cast<int>(szBuffer);
printf("My number is: %d\n", tester);
```

right after

```
printf("%s", szBuffer);
```

and I get the same result (1-2 errors after 5-6 correct ones).  I don't think the Arduino is sending bad data, since just a

```
printf("%s", szBuffer);
```

will never deviate from the number it's supposed to be.  Could the conversion be messing up the receiving of data?  Thanks.

EDIT: The Arduino code is:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); // same as in your c++ script
}

void loop() {
      Serial.print(51);
      delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With serial ports, there is no mechanism where a transmitter can inform a receiver how many bytes were transmitted as a block. I.e. there's no "hidden" marker where `Serial.print(51);` tells the receiver that it sent two characters as one number. You have to add some kind of indication (spaces, commas, line ends, initial byte counts, whatever) to your serial protocol.

Because of this, the number of characters you get from `serial.Read` depends on the number of characters you asked it to read (the second parameter) and how many characters are in the serial port's receive buffer, whichever is smaller. Most of the time, it seems the Arduino sends both digits before you call `serial.Read`, but sometimes it only gets one out in time... and the second is read the next time through the loop.

So let's assume you decided to use line ends to separate your numbers. All you have to do on the Arduino end is change to `Serial.println(51);`. The receive end is a little more complex.

I don't know what your serial library has in it. Most have some kind of "read line" function, and you would just replace the `serial.Read` call with something like:

```
serial.Readline(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer) - 1);
```

and it will take care of null-terminating the output. If it doesn't take care of null-termination, you'll need to find the line end and change it to a `\0` yourself. From this point on, your code will work fine, because the `serial.Readline` function will *block* until it gets the whole line.

If you don't have a "read line" or at least a "read until this character" function, it's a bit harder. You have to repeatedly call `serial.Read`, moving through your buffer, until you see the line end character. Further, you run the risk of reading part or all of the next line, so you can't just discard all the data you read when you're done reading the number; you have to move teh data in the buffer so the next line's data (and further) is at the start of the buffer.

---

If you're using Boost (are you? it has no `CSerial` that I see), it looks like it has a [read_until](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until/overload1.html) function. This takes three parameters: the stream you're reading from, a stream buffer to store the data in, and something to stop on. In this case, the stream buffer for storage is the one in your `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream buffer;
size_t chars = boost::asio::read_until(serial, buffer.rdbuf(), '\n');
if(chars == 0) return;
int tester;
buffer >> tester;
printf("My number is: %d\n", tester+1);
```

Comment: *Most of the time, it seems the Arduino sends both digits before you call serial.Read, but sometimes it only gets one out in time... and the second is read the next time through the loop.*



Isn't this supposed to not happen if they're using the same baud rate?

Also, I originally did have the Arduino using println, but I got an R6010 - abort error when using the Boost function.

The library doesn't seem to have a "read line" function.  I may have to implement the last one.  Thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with baud rate. If the baud rates are more than about 2% mismatched, it will garble the data. I've added how to get Boost to work with this.